# Why this flink scala code is failed to overloaded method value map with alternatives?

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

I tried this code in flink scala repl, and i build a RichMapFunction in java, but scala cannot work.
anyone could give me about scala method overload strategy document link?

### java rich map function

```
public class RichMapFunctions {

    public static class CountRichMapFunction<E, T> extends RichMapFunction<E, T> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private transient Counter counter;

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            this.counter = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().counter("demo");
        }

        @Override
        public T map(E value) throws Exception {
            this.counter.inc();
            return (T) value;
        }

    }

}
```

### java FlinkIMain extend IMain imports

```java
    private static String[] PACKAGE_IMPORTS = new String[] { //
        "org.apache.flink.core.fs._", //
        "org.apache.flink.core.fs.local._", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.common.io._", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.common.aggregators._", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.common.accumulators._", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.common.distributions._", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.common.operators._", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.base.JoinOperatorBase.JoinHint", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.common.functions._", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.java.io._", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.java.aggregation._", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.java.functions._", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.java.operators._", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.java.sampling._", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.scala._", //
        "org.apache.flink.api.scala.utils._", //
        "org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._", //
        "org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time._", //
        "com.gaff.sappo.dag.streaming.interpreter.RichMapFunctions.CountRichMapFunction" //
    };
```

### scala script for repl run

```scala
val text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)

val counts = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") filter { _.nonEmpty } }
  .map { (_, 1) }
  .map(new CountRichMapFunction()) // this code is error
  .keyBy(0)
val window = counts.timeWindow(Time.seconds(5)).sum(1)

window.print()
env.execute("Window Stream WordCount")
```

### the error json message

```
{"data":"<console>:69: error: overloaded method value map with alternatives:"}
{"data":"  [R](mapper: org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction[(String, Int),R])(implicit evidence$9: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[R])org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream[R] <and>"}
{"data":"  [R](fun: ((String, Int)) => R)(implicit evidence$8: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[R])org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream[R]"}
{"data":" cannot be applied to (com.gaff.sappo.dag.streaming.interpreter.RichMapFunctions.CountRichMapFunction[Nothing,Nothing])"}
{"data":"         .map(new CountRichMapFunction())"}
{"data":"          ^"}
```

Comment: I don't use flink, but it looks like the problem is that the compiler is not able to infer the generic types of your `RichMapFunction`, maybe if you specify them explicitly it will work.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for your help, but i try to defined a common function library for many different case, i cannot understand the scala generic type grammar for this case, have some reference document link for help.

Comment: It is not different from Java, only that it uses square braces _(`[T,U]`)_ instead of diamonds _(`<T,U>`)_ - also [**variance**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html), but you may omit that for now. However, what I said is that error messages says you passed an `CountRichMapFunction[Nothing,Nothing]` and it expected an`MapFunction[(String, Int),R]` - I suppose your `CountRichMap` inherits indirectly from `MapFunction`, so I believe the problem is with the generics, the compiler inferred `Nothing` for both, try being explicit `new CountRichMapFunction[(String, Int),(String, Int)]()`.

Comment: Also, since you have just an identity function, that always return the same element, but does a counting in the process, why don't you change your signature to `class CountRichMapFunction<T> extends RichMapFunction<T, T>` ?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes,is worked, thanks! ~~~~~ btw ......... sometimes I realy hate scala :(

Comment: It is easy to hate something you don't understand _(that may be the answer to every human conflict, but  this is not a place to discuss about philosophy)_. Anyways, I'm glad that was the fix, it was the first I tough after reading the error message, and as I don't know anything about flink I was not 100% sure.